# How do move approved documents from one document library into another in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013, and I am trying to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 that moves documents to another document library within a site once it has been approved or rejected.

I currently have a 2010 Approval Workflow in charge of approving or rejecting the document. What I would like to do is trigger a workflow based on the change of the column value to Approved or Rejected. If the document is approved, I would like that document to move to another document library for final review (moving can be copy the document to that library and deleting it from the original). I'd like the same thing to happen if the document was rejected, just moving it to a different document library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workflow that runs whenever an item is changed. Let the workflow check the status value and if the condition is met, copy the item to the other document library, then delete the item. These are all standard workflow actions.

Answer (score 0):

And you also could use content organizer to route documents. We can create content organizer rule to move the documents from one document library to another document library according to certain condition.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

Configure the Content Organizer to route documents.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a

Activating and Configuring the Content Organizer Feature.

https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/content-organizer/activating-configuring-the-content-organizer-feature-exercise.cfm